# How notifyAll() wakes up all the waiting threads simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading

I understand what notifyAll() does, but how it does. Suppose 10 threads are waiting on a condition and I call notify(), so any one of thread will be chosen and will be awakened. But when we call notifyAll() how all of them will be awakened so that each of them would get fair chance to be picked by scheduler to run. I am sure it won't be waking up threads sequentially.

Comment: What makes you think they all get a fair chance to be picked by the scheduler?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am curious about what is the strategy by which it wakes up all the threads at once to avoid conditions like if T1 is awakened before T2 so T1 may get chance to get run before T2.

Comment: Again, what makes you think that it *does* do that? I don't believe there's any guarantee of fairness.

Comment: I should explain the problem by example. Suppose I have 10 threads waiting then Will notiflyAll() iterate through all the threads and call notify() or something like that on each thread?

Comment: As per the JLS, "all threads are removed from m's wait set, and thus resume." There's no guarantee about which will reacquire the monitor (and thus return from `wait()`) first.

Comment: Just want to confirm if all the threads are removed from wait set one by one?

Comment: Why does it matter? I can't see that there's any guarantee of it happening "all at once" or "one at a time". If you try to write code *assuming* that any particular thread is more likely to be the first to return from `wait()`, that's a recipe for trouble.

Comment: You can enforce an order if you really need/want to, but you need a more complex thread-control mechanism than any simple notifyAll().  I'm struggling to think of any such requirement that is not a bad design anyway:)

Comment: The Java Language Spec leaves some details of threading unspecified (e.g., who runs first after a notifyAll() call).  Leaving them unspecified allows a JVM implementer to use native threads on whatever operating system instead of implementing less efficient "green threads."  As @JonSkeet said, the omission won't cause you any problems if you use the built-in synchronization mechanisms the way they were intended to be used.  And, as he also said, if the built-ins don't meet your needs, then you can always create your own synchronization by building on the available primitives.

Comment: Have you considered using a [fair Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#Semaphore%28int,%20boolean%29) ?